Would two antennas on the same board work well?
I'm building a circuit based on Nordic´s nRF91, my project involves making a compact solution for acquiring location, having to fit it to a small enclosure I'm thinking about making a board for both antennas that will stay on top of the circuit.
Here is my idea on the design of the board:

If both antennas shared the same ground place, would the efficiency be affected?
The LTE antenna would be matched to operate on the range of 1710 to 2690 MHz.

The shared ground will cause interference definitely, but It can be optimized by selecting proper antenna technique to minimize the interference or improve the isolation.
In this case, a customized antenna solution is preferred to achieve optimal for both antenna performance.
